# Cannot get signal-r transport type from Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, signalr

Upon a signal-r connection ... javascript can get the transport type using

```
this.connection.connection.transport.constructor.name
```

But the connection.transport isn't publicly available for Typescript.

How can I determine the transport type using Typescript?